# Why does many ruby based projects recommend compiling from source?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was using [Veewee](https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/blob/master/doc/requirements.md#ruby-environment), the VirtualBox image generator for Vagrant, and I noticed it advised to compile ruby from source using a version manager.
Now I had a look at RoR and I see the same [advice.](http://rubyonrails.org/download) I've been doing sysadmin work for a couple of years and I've never seen this requirement for Perl or Python.

Does the language has some specific requirements which make hand-compiled installations a need ? How to do people comply with this on servers ?

Comment: Usually ruby from the OS distro is quite old. That's why.

Comment: Most of rug versions installed in OS by default is 1.8, but, if you really like install ruby without effort, take a look at RVM or RBENV ( I prefer RVM)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: then it means Ruby based projects are less "conservative" about supporting older ruby versions ?